# Do I lose quality when scaling models?

Tags: scale

When scaling a model either from lower scale to higher or vice versa, do we lose any kind of quality?

My question might sound odd, sorry but I'm new to graphics design.

Comment: No, these are not raster graphics, increasing or decreasing scale shouldn't affect quality, unless we are talking about very extreme factors which reach float point precision limits

Comment: if you're using image texture though, make sure it's big enough so that it's not getting pixelated

Comment: thanks, very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mesh stays the same it just gets bigger. The UV map scales with the mesh as well so textures will appear the same as well.